# Spring @Autowire two beans of the same class which are not defined in ApplicationContext

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I am working on Spring MVC app and encountered a problem. I am new to Spring, so please forgive me if my working is a bit clumsy. Basically I have a java class ContractList. In my application I need two different objects of this class (both of them must be singleton)

```
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    private ContractList contractList;

    @Autowired
    private ContractList correctContractList;

    .. do something..
}
```

Note that both of these beans are not defined in ApplicationContext.xml. I am using only annotations. So when I try to access them - contractList and correctContractList end up referring to the same object. Is there a way to somehow differentiate them without defining them explicitly in ApplicationContext.xml ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can give qualifiers to the beans:

```
@Service("contractList")
public class DefaultContractList implements ContractList { ... }

@Service("correctContractList")
public class CorrectContractList implements ContractList { ... }
```

And use them like this:

```
public class MyClass {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("contractList")
    private ContractList contractList;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("correctContractList")
    private ContractList correctContractList;
}
```

In xml config still using `@Autowired` this would be:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="contractList" class="org.example.DefaultContractList" />
    <bean id="correctContractList" class="org.example.CorrectContractList" />

    <!-- The dependencies are autowired here with the @Qualifier annotation -->
    <bean id="myClass" class="org.example.MyClass" />
</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks! It is not like I am avoiding using xml definitions... I was curious if there is a way to do so without explicit definition in xml.

Answer (score 1):

In the case that you don't have access to the class annotated with `@Autowired` there may be another thing you can do. You might be able to take advantage of the `@Primary` annotation if the stars align in your favor.

Assume you have a library class you can't modify:

```
class LibraryClass{
   @Autowired
   ServiceInterface dependency; 
}
```

And another class that you *do* control:

```
class MyClass{
   @Autowired
   ServiceInterface dependency; 
}
```

Setup your config like so, and it should work:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ServiceInterface libraryService(){
  return new LibraryService();
}

@Bean
public ServiceInterface myService(){
  return new MyService();
}
```

And annotate `MyClass` with `Qualifier` to tell it to use `myService`. `LibraryClass` will use the bean annotated with `@Primary` and `MyClass` will use the other with this configuration:

```
class MyClass{
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("myService")
   ServiceInterface dependency; 
}
```

This is a rare use, but I used it in a situation where I had my own class that needed to use a legacy implementation as well as a new implementation.