# spring boot secondary datasource with primary auto configured

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i am trying to configure two jpa datasource , i did same as [this example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples) , every thing is good but is it possible to keep the auto configuration done automatically and just add a new one without having to create `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` manually.

```
 @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

@Bean
PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
}

@Bean
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);

    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.xxxxxxxx.common.domain","com.xxxxxxx.tekram.cdrserver.domain");

    return factoryBean;
}
```

Comment: That should just work as long as you mark one a `@Primary` .

Comment: For your second one you would have to configure it manually.

Comment: spring-boot will not autoconfigure LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean when one is configured for the secondary , my question is can i force it to auto create it

Comment: Doh. Yeah I was only thinking of the datasource, shouldn't mix things. But no you cannot force the auto creation as there is a conditional for it.

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38445537/autowire-multiple-data-sources-in-spring-boot/38445741#38445741) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516769/spring-autowire-two-beans-of-the-same-class-which-are-not-defined-in-applicatio). Short answer, use `@Qualifier`

Comment: @jundgingNotJudging you did not understand my question , spring boot auto configuration check if you have data source or LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean in class path and if yes it does not auto configure jpa , my question was can I keep the autoconfiguration and still decare a secondary data source .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not really sure about what's your concrete problem or what you wish to acomplish, but I'll show you how I've used two dataSources with Spring Boot using the auto configuration features:

Create config for every data source (in separate classes only to better reading):

PrimaryDbConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.aoc.dao", entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManager", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
public class PrimaryDBConfiguration {

 @Bean(name = "dataSource")      
 @Primary
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "primary.datasource")
 public DataSource dataSource() {
      return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
 }

 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary")   
 @Primary
 @Bean(name = "entityManager")
 public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
      return builder.dataSource(dataSource())
              .persistenceUnit("primary")                 
              .packages("com.aoc.model")
              .build();
 }

}
```

SecondaryDbConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.aoc.dao", entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondaryEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "secondaryTransactionManager")
public class SecondaryDBConfiguration {
  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "secondary.datasource")
   public DataSource secDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
   }
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "secondary")
  @Bean(name = "secondaryEntityManager")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
       return  builder.dataSource(secDataSource())                 
               .persistenceUnit("secondary")
               .packages("com.aoc.siri")
               .build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "secondaryTransactionManager")
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
         JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
         tm.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory(builder).getObject());
         tm.setDataSource(secDataSource());
         return tm;
   }       
}
```

Anotate every DAO with it's respective `PersistenceContext` `unitName`:

OneDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository(value = "OneDaoImpl")
public class OneDaoImpl {

@PersistenceContext(unitName="primary")
private EntityManager manager;

public List<One> getAllOne() {      
    return (List<One>) manager.createQuery("FROM ONE", One.class).getResultList();
}
}
```

AnotherDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository(value = "anotherDaoImpl")
public class AnotherDaoImpl {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "secondary")
private EntityManager manager;


public List<Another> getAllAnother() {      
    return (List<Another>) manager.createQuery("FROM Another", Another.class).getResultList();
}
}
```

Then in your `src/main/resources/application.properties`

```
primary.datasource.driver-class-name=...
primary.datasource.url=...
primary.datasource.username=xxx
primary.datasource.password=yyy

secondary.datasource.driver-class-name=...
secondary.datasource.url=...
secondary.datasource.username=zzz
secondary.datasource.password=xxx
```

As you probably know if you are using the [recommended Spring Boot packages naming](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html) with these classes and anotations you should be able to use that two dataSources at the same time.

Comment: the idea about this i wanted to add embedded database to my exisiting project without having to do all again manually . you above example worked perfectly except for   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect which was not loaded directly from properties